# GNUCASH: How to sort transactions by date without any influence of check number?

Tags: gnucash

By default GnuCash sorts transactions by date. But when a transaction has a check number, it places said transaction as the last transaction of that day.

I want to have transactions in the order I enter them. Even if a transaction has a check number, it should stay in the same order as I entered it and not move to the last transaction of the day.

PS I'm on GnuCash v4.6